# Is gulp-TSLint html reporter available?

Tags: typescript, npm, angular, gulp, tslint

I'm developing an angular2 app using npm, I want to validate my TS code using TSLint.I'm getting errors in cmd prompt,but I need html reporter. Is this option available in TSLint? Thanks in advance, Excuse mistakes,If any.

Answer (score 3):

Today I found one, I faced the same problem. I found one package - `tslint-html-report` in npm. You can use it with Gulp to build report.

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var tslintHtmlReport = require('tslint-html-report');

gulp.task('buildReport', function() {
      tslintHtmlReport({
      tslint: 'tslint.json',
      srcFiles: 'src/**/*.ts', 
      outDir: 'reports/tslint-html-report',
      html: 'tslint-report.html',
      breakOnError: false,
      typeCheck: true,
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json'
    });
});
```

And you can run it like this - `gulp buildReport`

Source Repo : https://github.com/SpitfireSatya/tslint-html-report

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from their documentation, https://github.com/palantir/tslint, available formatters are: prose, json, verbose, pmd, msbuild, checkstyle.